# Do not replace in between brackets in preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex

replace the text which is only outside the bracket not inside.

**I tried like this**

```
  $pro_name = samsung galaxy s3 (s3);
    $new_pro_name = preg_replace("/\b(s3)\b/i",***s5****,$pro_name);
    echo $new_pro_name;
```

**Expected Result:**

```
samsung galaxy ***s5**** (s3)
```

**Output:** 
    `samsung galaxy ***s5*** (***s5***)`

Comment: parenthesis are a regex operator, so use parenthesis like that: /\b\\(s3\\)\b/i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using negative lookback and lookahead http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

We can use the following:

```
$pro_name = 'samsung galaxy s3 (s3)';
$new_pro_name = preg_replace("/(?<!\()s3(?!\))/i", '***s5****', $pro_name);
echo $new_pro_name;
```

NOTE that `(?<!x)` looks back at previous character which must not be 'x'.
In you case this needs to be `(` but because this is a special character it needs to be escaped to `\(`

and `(?!x)` is look ahead for character that's not x.

for a breakdown of the special characters used in REGEX see php's `preg_quote();` http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Answer (score 1):

`(` and `)` have a meaning in regex, try escaping them with `\(` and `\)`.

Comment: look at `preg_quote();` for a list of what needs escaping http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: `the special regular expression characters are: . \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`

Comment: This is supposed to be a comment, does not answer the question

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
  $pro_name     = "samsung galaxy s3 (s3)";
  $new_pro_name = preg_replace("/(.*)s3(.*)\((.*)\)/i","$1s5$2($3)",$pro_name);
  echo $new_pro_name;
```

Output : `samsung galaxy s5 (s3)`

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Matches the text before and after s3 and text inside () and creates a new string with s3 reaplce to s5, Ref link http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php you will get a better idea

Comment: If it helped to resolve your issue, dont forget to accept it, it may help others to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `s3+(?=[^()]*(\(|$))`

It's using look ahead to confirm the brackets.

Example:

```
$pro_name = samsung galaxy s3 (s3);
$new_pro_name = preg_replace("/s3+(?=[^()]*(\(|$))/g", 's5', $pro_name);
echo $new_pro_name;
```